# Issue with Topbar input in Bootstrap css in ie

Tags: css, internet-explorer, input, twitter-bootstrap

When I create an input box in topbar using bootstrap css, the placeholder value is visible in all browsers except IE. But in twitter site they're making it visible somehow(not javascript, cause I turned off scripts and tested). Can anyone out there help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be good to see your code, but I'll assume you set the placeholder="my placeholder" attribute on the input tag. This is new HTML5 functionality, so that's why it is working without JavaScript.

There's a few reasons I can think of why it's not working.

1. Set your doctype correctly to html, which indicates html5.
2. Make sure there's nothing before the doctype declaration, not even empty lines.
3. Set your css-styles correctly. You'll have to use vendor prefixed
   since it's a relatively new feature:

---

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:#999; };
:-moz-placeholder { color:#999; };
:-ms-input-placeholder { color:#999; };
:placeholder { color:#999; };
.placeholder { color:#999; };
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having similar issues and faked the same placeholder functionality for IE by doing this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
    if(!$.support.placeholder) { 
        var active = document.activeElement;
        $(':text').focus(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('placeholder') != '' && $(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder')) {
                $(this).val('').removeClass('hasPlaceholder');
            }
        }).blur(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('placeholder') != '' && ($(this).val() == '' || $(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder'))) {
                $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder')).addClass('hasPlaceholder');
            }
        });
        $(':text').blur();
        $(active).focus();
        $('form').submit(function () {
            $(this).find('.hasPlaceholder').each(function() { $(this).val(''); });
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

***Source:** http://www.cssnewbie.com/cross-browser-support-for-html5-placeholder-text-in-forms/*

Comment: I know the javascript solution and I've mentioned that "it works after disabling javascript"